# How to find index of object in a JavaScript array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find the index of an object in an array in jquery.
I cannot use jQuery.inArray because i want to match objects on a certain property.
I am using:

```
jQuery.inObjectArray = function(arr, func)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            if(func(arr[i]))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
```

and then calling:

```
jQuery.inObjectArray([{Foo:"Bar"}], function(item){return item.Foo == "Bar"})
```

Is there a built in way?

Comment: Could be me, but is there any jQuery specific code in your example?

Comment: Do you only want the index or the object itself?

Comment: I want the index i think i can get the object with grep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why each() doesn't work for you:

BROKEN -- SEE FIX BELOW

```
function check(arr, closure)
{
    $.each(arr,function(idx, val){
       // Note, two options are presented below.  You only need one.
       // Return idx instead of val (in either case) if you want the index
       // instead of the value.

       // option 1.  Just check it inline.
       if (val['Foo'] == 'Bar') return val;

       // option 2.  Run the closure:
       if (closure(val)) return val;
    });
    return -1;
}
```

---

Additional example for Op comments.

```
Array.prototype.UContains = function(closure)
{
    var i, pLen = this.length;
    for (i = 0; i < pLen; i++)
    {
       if (closure(this[i])) { return i; } 
    }
    return -1;
}
// usage:
// var closure = function(itm) { return itm.Foo == 'bar'; };
// var index = [{'Foo':'Bar'}].UContains(closure);
```

---

Ok, my first example IS HORKED.  Pointed out to me after some 6 months and multiple upvotes.  : )

Properly, check() should look like this:

```
function check(arr, closure)
{
    var retVal = false; // Set up return value.
    $.each(arr,function(idx, val){
       // Note, two options are presented below.  You only need one.
       // Return idx instead of val (in either case) if you want the index
       // instead of the value.

       // option 1.  Just check it inline.
       if (val['Foo'] == 'Bar') retVal = true; // Override parent scoped return value.

       // option 2.  Run the closure:
       if (closure(val)) retVal = true;
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

The reason here is pretty simple... the scoping of the return was just wrong.

At least the prototype object version (the one I actually checked) worked.

Thanks Crashalot.  My bad.

Comment: Probably he used `$(arr).each()`

Comment: Thanks for this. I was actually looking for a function like inArray and like the function i wrote above that would not make me create a function like you just created. So to make my self clear is there a built in function that does what your function does. But perhaps i'm looking too far.

Comment: Yeah.  I actually don't like that about jQuery.... the names are all too overloaded.  Of course, the other side of that coin is something like PHP with its hundreds of un-namespaced top-level functions.

Comment: @Daniel - No, but that's sort of the point of JavaScript.  I added an additional example, which shows how to take a core object and extend it through its prototype.  Generally, this is a more advanced technique, and definitely prone to its own set of issues because it isn't very atomic.

Comment: Hi John, how did you get around this aspect of jQuery.each (taken from jQuery API): "We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."

Comment: @Crashalot - Well, great point.  : )  I've fixed the code above.

Comment: No problem, John. I have made far worse mistakes. :) BTW, still curious how this works since retVal returns true/false instead of an index value? We wound up solving this by setting an external variable equal to the index of the first matching value (and then breaking the loop by returning false).