# How to check if value exist in jQuery .data() function

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find index of object in a JavaScript array with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108034/how-to-find-index-of-object-in-a-javascript-array-with-jquery)

I need to find value of input entered if already exists in .data() function.

I am trying this way.

jQuery

```
var array = $("form[name=update]").data("values", {"v1": "value1", "v2": "value2", "v3": "value3", "v4": "value4", "v5": "value5"});

if ($.inArray("value1", array) > -1){alert("duplicate value")}
```

But it does nothing.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: `array` isn't an array; it's an instance of jQuery, and the values you are setting are in an object anyway.  Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @danronmoon Ok is there a way to find value if exist data function.

Comment: What are you trying to achiev? Tell us that and perhaps we can find a completely different solution

Comment: Grep: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758986/295783

Comment: @mplungjan i cant figure out how to use `$.grep`, can you suggest something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

`grep` (which does not do objects) did not work for me either.

Here is a $.each version

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ZLMTE/)

```
$(function() {
  $("form[name=update]").data("values", {"v1": "value11", "v2": "value2", "v3": "value3", "v4": "value4", "v5": "value5"});
  $(".but").on("click",function(e) {
    var fData = $("form[name=update]").data("values");
    var val = $(this).val();
      console.log(fData);
    $.each(fData, function(n,i) { 
        console.log("!!!",n,i)
      if (i===val) {
        alert("duplicate value");
        return false;
      }    
    })  
    e.preventDefault()  
  });
});
```

---

This is now I had a look, the same method as danronmoon's solution

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LzvMR/)

```
$(function() {
  $("form[name=update]").data("values", {"v1": "value11", "v2": "value2", "v3": "value3", "v4": "value4", "v5": "value5"});
  $(".but").on("click",function(e) {
    var fData = $("form[name=update]").data("values");
    var val = $(this).val();
      console.log(fData);
    for (var o in fData) { 
        console.log("!!!",o,fData[o])
      if (fData[o]===val) {
        alert("duplicate value");
        break;
      }    
    }  
    e.preventDefault()  
  });
});
```

Comment: Its giving false alert for value11, please see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LzvMR/15/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form[name=update]").data("values", {/* values here*/});

// then later
var valueToLookFor = 'value1',
    formData = $("form[name=update]").data().values;
for (var i in formData) {
     if (formData[i] === valueToLookFor) {
        // you found it!
     }
}
```

Comment: What is 'it'?  Please be more specific.  I took a stab at it, but you may have to update your question to be less ambiguous.

Comment: i tried like you suggest `formData = $("form[name=update]").data();
for (var i in formData) {if (formData[i] === 'value1') {alert('duplicate');}}` it didnt show any alert.

Comment: I just updated.  Try that

Comment: Still not working tried same way.

Comment: It works fine for me in the console.  Try using `console.log`s and seeing what's in `formData`.